# what does more than one Parameterized Types mean?

Tags: scala

I'm learning some Scala example from somewhere, it looks like as below:

```
class className[T <: classTypeA : classTypeB](some args)....
```

Or:

```
class className[T<:classTypeA with trait1](some args)...
```

Some tutorial explain that `T <: classTypeA` means `T` must be the subclass of `classTypeA`.
I don't understand why there are two types after `<:`, and what `with trait1` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class className[T <: classTypeA : classTypeB](some args)
```

In this declaration `classTypeB` is a *type class* and this is equivalent to

```
class className[T <: classTypeA](some args)(implicit ev: classTypeB[T])
```

There must be a suitable instance of `classTypeB[T]` in scope for this to compile. This allows fine-grain control of which types are accepted as parameters to the class.

---

```
class className[T <: classTypeA with trait1](some args)
```

This declaration says that `T` must be a subclass of the type `classTypeA with trait1`.